# Delete characters from specific type of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with multiple types of cells:

```
53013

71767_os

25231_bl_OS

90886040

CH1050
```

Now I need a VBA code for deleting the alphabet from these two types of cells

```
71767_os

25231_bl_OS
```

The text after the 5 numbers can be of various length. The macro can't alter the rest of the types. What would be the best solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you practically need only to keep the numeric part, or only the first 5 digits? What does "The macro can't alter the rest of the types" mean? What do you need to be returned from a string like "25231_bl_OS_234"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function , the function allays return all digits and only digit from a string .

```
Function regexDigitOnly(ByVal strValue As String) As String
 
Dim szLine As String
Dim regex As Object '  New RegExp
Dim colregmatch ' As MatchCollection
Dim Item As Object
On Error Resume Next

Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regex
   .MultiLine = True
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
End With
regex.Pattern = "[0-9]"
If regex.test(strValue) Then
 Set colregmatch = regex.Execute(strValue)
    For Each Item In colregmatch
        If szLine = "" Then
            szLine = Item
        Else
            szLine = szLine & Item
        End If
    Next
End If

regexDigitOnly = szLine
Set regex = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of all that looping, you could use the `.Replace` method with a negated character class and just a single step::  `regex.Pattern = "[^0-9]" : regexDigitOnly = regex.Replace(strValue, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, I managed to do exactly what I need using:

```
cell = Split(cell, "_")(0)
```

Yes it was this easy. Sorry for asking.